# Is it possible to use gRPC Google APIs from Rust today?

Tags: google-api, rust, grpc

There is a [prehistoric example](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis.github.io/blob/0c60b8c7ca1bf52a35b3e9e6d88cfbd463d226c7/examples/rpc/rust/src/main.rs) where `protobuf` crate is used with `reqwest`  HTTP client to call one of the few [whitelisted services](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys) that can used with permanent API keys instead of OAuth / service accounts. This doesn't work with most of the [googleapis](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/firestore/v1beta1/firestore.proto) zoo.

Furthermore, using OAuth with gRPC doesn't seem as simple as attaching a `Authorization: Bearer`*`SIGNED_JWT`* to the request. As seen in all the [*Authenticate with Google* examples](https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/) on grpc.io, this requires calling the `grpc_composite_channel_credentials_create` function in [the C core library](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/db96d5d6ed5bb92651612c5a3d9110eb17d3df8d/src/core/lib/security/credentials/composite/composite_credentials.cc#L198-L209).

It looks like `pingcap/grpc-rs` doesn't [wrap](https://github.com/pingcap/grpc-rs/blob/94fcfbc74f155efaefd37dbda819bccdd8f47f80/grpc-sys/grpc_wrap.cc) or [use](https://github.com/pingcap/grpc-rs/blob/1147191fdbd702458c63450dfb217c73659f78bb/src/credentials.rs) this function. However, it does [mention Google OAuth](https://github.com/pingcap/grpc-rs/blob/1147191fdbd702458c63450dfb217c73659f78bb/src/credentials.rs#L227) suddenly.

What is the truth?

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what exactly the authorization constitutes on the wire, but
`google_default_credentials` successfully allows me to call Google APIs.
In fact, it not only works with `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env var pointing to the service account key `.json` but even magically uses my signed in google account from `gcloud` cli.

For example with `pingcap/grpc-rs` aka `grpcio = "0.5.0-alpha.3"` all it took was

```rust
    let env = Arc::from(EnvBuilder::new().build());
    let creds = ChannelCredentials::google_default_credentials().unwrap();
    let ch = ChannelBuilder::new(env).secure_connect("firestore.googleapis.com", creds);
    let client = FirestoreClient::new(ch);
```